# How to Install Civi on a Subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, installation, install

I am installing civi 4.7.27 on a subdomain ( civiinstall.mysite.com ) that will run on WordPress 4.9.1.

Has anyone installed Civi on a subdomain before?  Do we need to update the paths somewhere as some of the feature such as CKeditor aren't loading and CiviMail is just a blank screen?

Thank you.

Errors
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
angular.js:4692 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4692
    at q (angular.js:325)
    at g (angular.js:4653)
    at fb (angular.js:4575)
    at c (angular.js:1809)
    at Gc (angular.js:1830)
    at se (angular.js:1715)
    at HTMLDocument. (angular.js:32616)
    at i (jquery.min.js?r=54zOZ:2)

Comment: I would recommend that you open the Inspector, check if there are Javascript errors and add them to your question of you find any.

Comment: Thank you. I posted some errors above, but I am really just asking a simple question; When installing Civi on Subdomain, are there some extra steps that need to be taken?  Does anyone know from experience, and what those steps are?

Comment: I have installed Civi on a sub domain several times using the standard install process, nothing different.  This was on Drupal but I don't see that this would be different for WP

Comment: I just went to Settings - Debugging and Error Handling and disabled Asset Caching, Now everything is loading properly, but I don't think that is right.  Shouldn't Asset Caching be enabled or on Auto?